# Java PDF renderer with CSS3

Tags: java, api, pdf, flying-saucer

I need to generate a pdf from an html using css3. I found some api's like flying saucer, but unfortunately it is only working with css 2.1. Is there any chance to do it with css3?

Comment: i am using http://wkhtmltopdf.org/  for that . it is a command line tool and works pretty well perhaps it can fit you

Comment: Hi, it is a web application and I really need to do it inside Java, Spring MVC

Comment: princeXML is a good solution but commercial...  http://www.princexml.com/

Comment: You can make flying saucer render SVGs and interpret data/urls with base64 images via extension, no css3 though.

Comment: There is a fork of the FS project under the name "neoflyingsaucer" which contains many of the CSS3 stylings. Heres a link to their github https://github.com/danfickle/neoflyingsaucer